# Which Currency can I use in Georgia?

Tags: international-travel, money, exchange, georgia-country

Which currency is generally used in Georgia? Will I be able to use Euro or US dollars?
And if no, how much will I be allowed to exchange at Tbilisi airport?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that Georgia has its own currency?

Comment: Avoid paying with EUR/USD in places that accept them. It's occasionally possible to pay in these currencies, but the exchange rates amount to robbery.

Answer (score 11):

According to [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/georgia/money-costs):

> - Georgia’s currency is the lari (GEL). It has been fairly stable since    it was introduced in 1995. One lari is divided into 100
>     tetri.
> - Banknotes come in denominations of one, two, five, 10, 20, 50, 100    and 200 lari; coins run from one tetri to two lari.
> - ATMs, generally accepting MasterCard, Visa, Cirrus and Maestro cards,    are plentiful in cities and towns.
> - There are also plenty of banks and small money-exchange offices in    most towns and cities, where you can exchange US dollars, euros and
>     sometimes sterling and the currencies of Georgia's neighbouring
>     countries.
> - You can make purchases with credit cards at some hotels, restaurants    and shops, though less frequently outside Tbilisi.
> - Common tipping practice in restaurants is just to round up the bill    to the next round number.

As for [exchanging money at the airport](http://www.tbilisiairport.com/en-EN/airportguide/Pages/BanksandCurrencyExchangeOffices.aspx), there are 5 different banks and 6 ATMs that you could exchange money or withdraw money from. Each bank has it's own policy on the maximum amount of currency to exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I was in Georgia a month ago and I have never seen any price in a currency different than Lari or a announcement that any other currency is accepted.

There are many exchange offices in Tbilisi and a couple in the airport. Exchange rate in the airport is not worse than in the city in general (and even better than in some places).

It seems that there is no maximum amount that you can exchange (I have exchanged up to 300€ without any problem). Be prepared to present your pass or other ID.

Comment: I hope a Portuguese National ID card will be enough to get me around. Thanks for the info